# Splitting number and adding zeros to the left

Tags: split, addition, zero, fold, alternating

First, 0's are left attached to the resulting  number until the length is a multiple of the entered number ( f.x. `int a = 3` -> the length of the number should be the multiple of the number 3). Then i have to split the number into sections of length `a` (i.e. `3`).

---

For example:

Starting with `int a = 3` and the number: 9056737152

If the number is split without the leading zeros, one of the resulting sections will have a length of 1:

9056737152 -> 905 673 715 **2**

Since `1 <> a`, zeros need to be added to the left until the split results in all sections having a length of `a`, i.e.

009056737152 -> 009 056 737 152

009056737152 -> 009 (**section 1**) 056 (**section 2**) 737 (**section 3**) 152 (**section 4**)

---

Next, alternating sections need to be reversed, then all the sections added together. For example, reversing sections **2** and **4**:

251 + 737 + 650 + 009 = 1647

---

Any ideas ? I am on the first step, trying to add zeros with:

```
int num = 5;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00000");
System.out.println(df.format(zahl));
```

The problem is that the number `5` can't be static.

---

Another method:

```
int number = 9;      
String str = String.format("%04d", 9);  // 0009      
System.out.printf("original number %d, numeric string with padding : %s", 9, str);
```

- % denotes that it's a formatting instruction
- 0 is a flag which says to pad with zero
- 4 denotes length of formatted String. This will ensure that the right number of zero's will be added
- d is for decimal which means the next argument should be an integral value e.g. byte, char, short, int or long.

I need to change the 04 (from the formatting -- `"%04d"`) to my integer `a`.

Comment: When we revert chunks, then 009 056 737 152 must be 251 + 737 + 650 + 900 = 2538. 900, not 009. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution using JS

```js
const multiple = 3;
const number = 9056737152;
const strNumber = number.toString();
const zero = '0';

const needToAdd = multiple - strNumber.length % multiple;
const padded = zero.repeat(needToAdd).concat(strNumber);

const chunks = [];

for (let i = 0; i < padded.length / multiple; i++) {
  let chunk = padded.slice(i * multiple, (i + 1) * multiple);
  chunk = reverseString(chunk);
  chunks.push(chunk);
}

const sum = chunks.reduce((total, chunk) => {
  return total + parseInt(chunk, 10);
}, 0);

console.log(sum);

function reverseString(str) {
  const symbols = str.split('');
  symbols.reverse();

  return symbols.reduce((total, l) => {
    return total.concat(l)
  });
}
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: nice thanks :D iam not that much into javascript but i will try my best to get it Run in java :D

Comment: sorry i cant convert it to java :(

Comment: I hope you will find a solution)